# Problems with OpenCL helloworld

Tags: opencl

i´m new to OpenCl and i´m trying to learn it right know.
I installed Intel® SDK for OpenCL™ Applications and now i´m trying to use it with visual studio 2015.
When i´m trying to run an hello world example it returns an error at the    "program.build" -part in the following codepart.

Can somebody tell me what i´m missing?

Thanks :)

The consol returns this:

```
Using platform: Intel<R> OpenCL
Using device: Intel<R> Core<TM> i7-3770 CPU e 3.40 GHz
-44
Error building:
```

Examplecode:

```
//get all platforms (drivers)
std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
if (all_platforms.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << " No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}

cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];
std::cout << "Using platform: " << default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "\n";

//get default device of the default platform
std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
if (all_devices.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << " No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}
cl::Device default_device = all_devices[0];
std::cout << "Using device: " << default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << "\n";


cl::Context context({ default_device });

cl::Program::Sources sources;

// kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
std::string kernel_code =
    "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C){       "
    "       C[get_global_id(0)]=A[get_global_id(0)]+B[get_global_id(0)];                 "
    "   }                                                                               ";
sources.push_back({ kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length() });



cl::Program program(context, sources);
if (**program.build({ default_device }) != CL_SUCCESS**) {
std::cout << program.build({ default_device }) <<"\n";
std::cout << " Error building: " <<    program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device) << "\n";
exit(1);
}
```

Comment: which error code? if it is compile error, could you get the error string showing source of programming error in opencl-c?

Comment: When i´m using this: std::cout << program.build({ default_device }) <<"\n"; i get a -44

Comment: i got following message: Exception thrown at 0x7558C54F in OpenCLProject3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Intel::OpenCL::DeviceBackend::Exceptions::CompilerException at memory location 0x0056F5FC.

Comment: maybe he platform is an experimental one that is buggy? which version? opencl 1.2 or 2.x?

Comment: i´m using the 1.2 version. Do I have installed everything that i need to run OpenCV or is anything besides the sdk downloaded from here (https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl) necessary? i appreciate your help, i´m quite lost :x

Comment: I think you should try compubench site to know how many platorms and devices seen. also intel's visualstudio add-on has an option to query platforms and devices

Comment: The fact that you're calling `program.build` twice in this program is a bit concerning. Store the result of `program.build` into a variable and then compare it in the `if` statement and output it to the stream using that variable.

Comment: @Xirema - changed it, but output is the same   @ huseyin turgrul buyukisik  - the installation of compu bench errors with a network error, sadly can´t figure out how to solve this :/

Comment: -44 is "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM" which means the `program` parameter to the `build` method is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Error code -44 means that "the program object is invalid". However this is inconclusive and hints to some other issue that corrupts memory. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63263231/9178992).

Calling `program.build()` twice is - although not good practice - not the issue here, but maybe some threading issues? The problem certainly is not in the code snipped you provided.