# How can the OpenCL error code -44 CL_INVALID_PROGRAM appear if program is valid?

Tags: opencl

In some seemingly random, but reproducible occasions, `program.build(...)` returns error `-44` which means `CL_INVALID_PROGRAM`, so `program` is supposed to be invalid. However `program` is declared in the line above, only depending on `context` and `source`. I have checked that `source` is valid (no errors in `kernel_code`) and `context` only depends on `device` and `device` is also valid (tested on Nvidia Titan Xp and GTX 960M). How can `program` not be valid then?

```c
Context context = Context(device);
string kernel_code = opencl_code();
Program::Sources source;
source.push_back({ kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length() });
Program program = Program(context, source);
int error = program.build("-cl-fast-relaxed-math -w");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually because you already brought the driver into an unstable state earlier in your application. You need to pay utmost attention to threading issues (including which APIs are guaranteed to be threadsafe and which are not) and potential heap corruptions (use after free, buffer overflows) when dealing with the graphic APIs, the implementations behind are easily corrupted.

`CL_INVALID_PROGRAM` and other errors are often misleading, and occur at an apparently unrelated point in time. Specifically, they just indicate that any internal error check has failed, but are rarely mapped in a meaningful way.

If you can actually reproduce this in a minimal, reproducible example (that means: not in the context of a full application, and without any multi threading) then your best hope is to file a bug with NVidia.

If not reproducible in a minimal example, then it's almost certain that you caused undefined behavior somewhere else in your application.

Comment: It happens in combination with MPI, when I run kernels from multiple MPI threads on the same GPU (for testing the MPI parallelization if I only have 1 GPU available). Usually that works without issues. Source of the error seems to be threading issues as you pointed out, but I have no idea where to start searching.

Comment: When on Windows, Intel's Inspector would be the first approach. On Linux, valgrind with the helgrind tool.