# What can cause CL_INVALID_CONTEXT (-34) on clCreateBuffer?

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm using a 2015 MacBook Pro and using the Iris Pro device and when I try to allocate 1024 int of memory using clCreateBuffer `clCreateBuffer(context, flags, v.size() * sizeof(int), NULL, &error)` I get error CL_INVALID_CONTEXT (-34) but the context didn't return error and I even created a command queue with it.
Any idea?.

Comment: You should provide more "context" to get some help. Do you have any opencl code working?. If not first things first, try running clinfo command to check your platform, devices and to know your opencl version. Afterwards, you may compile some examples from [hands on opencl](https://handsonopencl.github.io/). They have opencl code on c, c++ and python.

Comment: It might be a threading issue as pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63263399/9178992

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I was releasing the context `clReleaseContext` before `clCreateBuffer`. That happened because I'm using clases and in the destructor I put the `clReleaseContext` and I didn't realize the destructor was getting called.