# N-body OpenCL code : error CL_​OUT_​OF_​HOST_​MEMORY with GPU card NVIDIA A6000

Tags: c++, linux, opencl, nvidia, nvlink

I would like to make run an old N-body which uses OpenCL.

I have 2 cards NVIDIA A6000 with `NVLink`, a component which binds from an hardware (and maybe software ?) point of view these 2 GPU cards.

But at the execution, I get the following result:

[image: kernel failed]

Here is the kernel code used (I have put pragma that I estimate useful for NVIDIA cards):

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

__kernel
void
nbody_sim(
    __global double4* pos ,
    __global double4* vel,
    int numBodies,
    double deltaTime,
    double epsSqr,
    __local double4* localPos,
    __global double4* newPosition,
    __global double4* newVelocity)
{
    unsigned int tid = get_local_id(0);
    unsigned int gid = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int localSize = get_local_size(0);

    // Gravitational constant
    double G_constant = 227.17085e-74;

    // Number of tiles we need to iterate
    unsigned int numTiles = numBodies / localSize;

    // position of this work-item
    double4 myPos = pos[gid];
    double4 acc = (double4) (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    for(int i = 0; i < numTiles; ++i)
    {
        // load one tile into local memory
        int idx = i * localSize + tid;
        localPos[tid] = pos[idx];

        // Synchronize to make sure data is available for processing
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        // Calculate acceleration effect due to each body
        // a[i->j] = m[j] * r[i->j] / (r^2 + epsSqr)^(3/2)
        for(int j = 0; j < localSize; ++j)
        {
            // Calculate acceleration caused by particle j on particle i
            double4 r = localPos[j] - myPos;
            double distSqr = r.x * r.x  +  r.y * r.y  +  r.z * r.z;
            double invDist = 1.0f / sqrt(distSqr + epsSqr);
            double invDistCube = invDist * invDist * invDist;
            double s = G_constant * localPos[j].w * invDistCube;

            // accumulate effect of all particles
            acc += s * r;
        }

        // Synchronize so that next tile can be loaded
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    double4 oldVel = vel[gid];

    // updated position and velocity
    double4 newPos = myPos + oldVel * deltaTime + acc * 0.5f * deltaTime * deltaTime;
    newPos.w = myPos.w;
    double4 newVel = oldVel + acc * deltaTime;

    // write to global memory
    newPosition[gid] = newPos;
    newVelocity[gid] = newVel;
}
```

The part of code which sets up the Kernel code is below:

```
int NBody::setupCL()
{
  cl_int status = CL_SUCCESS;
  cl_event writeEvt1, writeEvt2;

  // The block is to move the declaration of prop closer to its use
  cl_command_queue_properties prop = 0;
  commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(
      context,
      devices[current_device],
      prop,
      &status);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR( status, "clCreateCommandQueue failed.");

    ...

// create a CL program using the kernel source
  const char *kernelName = "NBody_Kernels.cl";
  FILE *fp = fopen(kernelName, "r");
  if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  char *source = (char*)malloc(10000);
  int sourceSize = fread( source, 1, 10000, fp);
  fclose(fp);

  // Create a program from the kernel source
  program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source, (const size_t *)&sourceSize, &status);

  // Build the program
  status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  // get a kernel object handle for a kernel with the given name
  kernel = clCreateKernel(
      program,
      "nbody_sim",
      &status);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clCreateKernel failed.");

  status = waitForEventAndRelease(&writeEvt1);
  CHECK_ERROR(status, NBODY_SUCCESS, "WaitForEventAndRelease(writeEvt1) Failed");

  status = waitForEventAndRelease(&writeEvt2);
  CHECK_ERROR(status, NBODY_SUCCESS, "WaitForEventAndRelease(writeEvt2) Failed");

  return NBODY_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, the errors occurs at the creation of the **Kernel code**. Is there a way to consider `the 2 GPU` as a unique GPU with `NVLINK component` ? I mean from a software point of view ?

How can I fix this error of creation of **Kernel code** ?

### Update 1

I) I have voluntarily restricted the number of GPU devices to only one GPU by modifying this loop below (actually, it remains only one iteration):

```
  // Print device index and device names
  //for(cl_uint i = 0; i < deviceCount; ++i)
  for(cl_uint i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
  {
    char deviceName[1024];
    status = clGetDeviceInfo(deviceIds[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(deviceName), deviceName, NULL);
    CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clGetDeviceInfo failed");

    std::cout << "Device " << i << " : " << deviceName <<" Device ID is "<<deviceIds[i]<< std::endl;
  }

  // Set id = 0 for currentDevice with deviceType
  *currentDevice = 0;

  free(deviceIds);

  return NBODY_SUCCESS;
}
```

and doing after the classical call:

```
 status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But error remains, below the message:

[image: only one gpu]

II) If I don't modify this loop and apply the solution suggested,i.e set `devices[current_device]` instead of `devices` I get a compilation error like this:

```
In file included from NBody.hpp:8,
                 from NBody.cpp:1:
/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/include/CL/cl.h:863:16: note:   initializing argument 3 of ‘cl_int clBuildProgram(cl_program, cl_uint, _cl_device_id* const*, const char*, void (*)(cl_program, void*), void*)’
                const cl_device_id * /* device_list */,
```

How could I circumvent this issue of compilation ?

### Update 2

I have printed the values of `status` variable in this portion of my code:

[image: code snippet]

and I get a value for `status = -44`. From `CL/cl.h`, it would correspond to a `CL_INVALID_PROGRAM` error:

[image: error code]

and then, when I execute the application, I get:

[image: execution]

I wonder if I didn't miss to put special pragma in kernel code since i am using OpenCL on NVIDIA cards, don't I ?

By the way, what is the type of the variables `devices` ? I can't manage to print it correctly.

### Update 3

I have added the following lines but still `-44 error` at the execution. Instead of putting all the concerned code, I provide the following link to download the source file: http://31.207.36.11/NBody.cpp and the Makefile used for compilation: http://31.207.36.11/Makefile . Maybe someone will find some errors but I would like mostly know why I get this `error -44` .

### Update 4

I am taking over this project.

Here is the result of clinfo command:

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 11.4.94
  Platform Name:                 NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor:               NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_khr_gl_event cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_nv_kernel_attribute cl_khr_device_uuid cl_khr_pci_bus_info


  Platform Name:                 NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices:               2
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Vendor ID:                     10deh
  Max compute units:                 84
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               1024
    Max work items[1]:               1024
    Max work items[2]:               64
  Max work group size:               1024
  Preferred vector width char:           1
  Preferred vector width short:          1
  Preferred vector width int:            1
  Preferred vector width long:           1
  Preferred vector width float:          1
  Preferred vector width double:         1
  Native vector width char:          1
  Native vector width short:             1
  Native vector width int:           1
  Native vector width long:          1
  Native vector width float:             1
  Native vector width double:            1
  Max clock frequency:               1800Mhz
  Address bits:                  64
  Max memory allocation:             12762480640
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       256
  Max number of images write arguments:      32
  Max image 2D width:                32768
  Max image 2D height:               32768
  Max image 3D width:                16384
  Max image 3D height:               16384
  Max image 3D depth:                16384
  Max samplers within kernel:            32
  Max size of kernel argument:           4352
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      4096
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
  Cache type:                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:               128
  Cache size:                    2408448
  Global memory size:                51049922560
  Constant buffer size:              65536
  Max number of constant args:           9
  Local memory type:                 Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                 49152
  Max pipe arguments:                0
  Max pipe active reservations:          0
  Max pipe packet size:              0
  Max global variable size:          0
  Max global variable preferred total size:  0
  Max read/write image args:             0
  Max on device events:              0
  Queue on device max size:          0
  Max on device queues:              0
  Queue on device preferred size:        0
  SVM capabilities:
    Coarse grain buffer:             Yes
    Fine grain buffer:               No
    Fine grain system:               No
    Atomics:                     No
  Preferred platform atomic alignment:       0
  Preferred global atomic alignment:         0
  Preferred local atomic alignment:      0
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     32
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        0
  Profiling timer resolution:            1000
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             No
  Queue on Host properties:
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Queue on Device properties:
    Out-of-Order:                No
    Profiling :                  No
  Platform ID:                   0x1e97440
  Name:                      NVIDIA RTX A6000
  Vendor:                    NVIDIA Corporation
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 1.2
  Driver version:                470.57.02
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_khr_gl_event cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_nv_kernel_attribute cl_khr_device_uuid cl_khr_pci_bus_info


  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Vendor ID:                     10deh
  Max compute units:                 84
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               1024
    Max work items[1]:               1024
    Max work items[2]:               64
  Max work group size:               1024
  Preferred vector width char:           1
  Preferred vector width short:          1
  Preferred vector width int:            1
  Preferred vector width long:           1
  Preferred vector width float:          1
  Preferred vector width double:         1
  Native vector width char:          1
  Native vector width short:             1
  Native vector width int:           1
  Native vector width long:          1
  Native vector width float:             1
  Native vector width double:            1
  Max clock frequency:               1800Mhz
  Address bits:                  64
  Max memory allocation:             12762578944
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:       256
  Max number of images write arguments:      32
  Max image 2D width:                32768
  Max image 2D height:               32768
  Max image 3D width:                16384
  Max image 3D height:               16384
  Max image 3D depth:                16384
  Max samplers within kernel:            32
  Max size of kernel argument:           4352
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      4096
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                     Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
  Cache type:                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:               128
  Cache size:                    2408448
  Global memory size:                51050315776
  Constant buffer size:              65536
  Max number of constant args:           9
  Local memory type:                 Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                 49152
  Max pipe arguments:                0
  Max pipe active reservations:          0
  Max pipe packet size:              0
  Max global variable size:          0
  Max global variable preferred total size:  0
  Max read/write image args:             0
  Max on device events:              0
  Queue on device max size:          0
  Max on device queues:              0
  Queue on device preferred size:        0
  SVM capabilities:
    Coarse grain buffer:             Yes
    Fine grain buffer:               No
    Fine grain system:               No
    Atomics:                     No
  Preferred platform atomic alignment:       0
  Preferred global atomic alignment:         0
  Preferred local atomic alignment:      0
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     32
  Error correction support:          0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:        0
  Profiling timer resolution:            1000
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                     Yes
  Compiler available:                Yes
  Execution capabilities:
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:             No
  Queue on Host properties:
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :                  Yes
  Queue on Device properties:
    Out-of-Order:                No
    Profiling :                  No
  Platform ID:                   0x1e97440
  Name:                      NVIDIA RTX A6000
  Vendor:                    NVIDIA Corporation
  Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 1.2
  Driver version:                470.57.02
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
  Extensions:                    cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_khr_gl_event cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_nv_kernel_attribute cl_khr_device_uuid cl_khr_pci_bus_info
```

So I have one platform with 2 GPU cards A6000.

Given the fact that I want to make run the original version of my code (i.e using a `single GPU card`), I have to select only one ID in the source `NBody.cpp` (I will see in a second time how to manage with 2 GPU cards but this is for after). So, I have just modified in this source.

Instead of:

```
  // Print device index and device names
  for(cl_uint i = 0; i < deviceCount; ++i)
  {
    char deviceName[1024];
    status = clGetDeviceInfo(deviceIds[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(deviceName), deviceName, NULL);
    CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clGetDeviceInfo failed");

    std::cout << "Device " << i << " : " << deviceName <<" Device ID is "<<deviceIds[i]<< std::endl;
  }
```

I did:

```
// Print device index and device names
  //for(cl_uint i = 0; i < deviceCount; ++i)
  for(cl_uint i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
  {
    char deviceName[1024];
    status = clGetDeviceInfo(deviceIds[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(deviceName), deviceName, NULL);
    CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clGetDeviceInfo failed");

    std::cout << "Device " << i << " : " << deviceName <<" Device ID is "<<deviceIds[i]<< std::endl;
  }
```

As you can see, I have forced to take into account `deviceIds[0]`, that is to say, a single GPU card.

A critical point is also the part of building program.

```
  // create a CL program using the kernel source 
  const char *kernelName = "NBody_Kernels.cl";
  FILE *fp = fopen(kernelName, "r");
  if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  char *source = (char*)malloc(10000);
  int sourceSize = fread( source, 1, 10000, fp);
  fclose(fp);

  // Create a program from the kernel source
  program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source, (const size_t *)&sourceSize, &status);

  // Build the program
  //status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &devices[current_device], NULL, NULL, NULL);
  printf("status1 = %d\n", status);
  //printf("devices = %d\n", devices[current_device]);

  // get a kernel object handle for a kernel with the given name
  kernel = clCreateKernel(
      program,
      "nbody_sim",
      &status);
  printf("status2 = %d\n", status);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clCreateKernel failed.");
```

At the execution, I get the following values for `status1` and `status2`:

```
Selected Platform Vendor : NVIDIA Corporation
deviceCount = 2/nDevice 0 : NVIDIA RTX A6000 Device ID is 0x55c38207cdb0
status1 = -44
devices = -2113661720
status2 = -44
clCreateKernel failed.
clSetKernelArg failed. (updatedPos)
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed.
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed.
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed.
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed.
```

The first error is a failed creation of kernel. Here my `NBody_Kernels.cl` source:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

__kernel
void 
nbody_sim(
    __global double4* pos ,
    __global double4* vel,
    int numBodies,
    double deltaTime,
    double epsSqr,
    __local double4* localPos,
    __global double4* newPosition,
    __global double4* newVelocity)
{
    unsigned int tid = get_local_id(0);
    unsigned int gid = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int localSize = get_local_size(0);

    // Gravitational constant
    double G_constant = 227.17085e-74;

    // Number of tiles we need to iterate
    unsigned int numTiles = numBodies / localSize;

    // position of this work-item
    double4 myPos = pos[gid];
    double4 acc = (double4) (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    for(int i = 0; i < numTiles; ++i)
    {
        // load one tile into local memory
        int idx = i * localSize + tid;
        localPos[tid] = pos[idx];

        // Synchronize to make sure data is available for processing
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        // Calculate acceleration effect due to each body
        // a[i->j] = m[j] * r[i->j] / (r^2 + epsSqr)^(3/2)
        for(int j = 0; j < localSize; ++j)
        {
            // Calculate acceleration caused by particle j on particle i
            double4 r = localPos[j] - myPos;
            double distSqr = r.x * r.x  +  r.y * r.y  +  r.z * r.z;
            double invDist = 1.0f / sqrt(distSqr + epsSqr);
            double invDistCube = invDist * invDist * invDist;
            double s = G_constant * localPos[j].w * invDistCube;

            // accumulate effect of all particles
            acc += s * r;
        }

        // Synchronize so that next tile can be loaded
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    double4 oldVel = vel[gid];

    // updated position and velocity
    double4 newPos = myPos + oldVel * deltaTime + acc * 0.5f * deltaTime * deltaTime;
    newPos.w = myPos.w;
    double4 newVel = oldVel + acc * deltaTime;

    // write to global memory
    newPosition[gid] = newPos;
    newVelocity[gid] = newVel;
}
```

The modified source can be found here:

[last modified code](http://31.207.36.11/stack/NBody.cpp)

I don't know how to solve the creation of this Kernel code and the following values `status1 = -44` and `status2 = -44`.

### Update 5

I have added `clGetProgramBuildInfo` to the code the following snippet to be able to see what's wrong with the `clCreateKernl failed` error:

```
// Create a program from the kernel source
  program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source, (const size_t *)&sourceSize, &status);

  if (clBuildProgram(program, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    // Determine the size of the log
    size_t log_size;
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[current_device], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);
    // Allocate memory for the log
    char *log = (char *) malloc(log_size);

    cout << "size log =" << log_size << endl;
    // Get the log
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, devices[current_device], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, log, NULL);

    // Print the log
    printf("%s\n", log);
    }


  // get a kernel object handle for a kernel with the given name
  kernel = clCreateKernel(
      program,
      "nbody_sim",
      &status);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clCreateKernel failed.");
```

Unfortunately, this function `clGetProgramBuildInfo` only gives the output:

```
Selected Platform Vendor : NVIDIA Corporation
Device 0 : NVIDIA RTX A6000 Device ID is 0x562857930980
size log =16
log =
clCreateKernel failed.
```

How can I print the content of "`value`" ?

### Update 6

If I do a `printf` on :

```
  // Create a program from the kernel source
  program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source, (const size_t *)&sourceSize, &status);
printf("status clCreateProgramWithSourceContext = %d\n", status);
```

I get an `status=-6` which corresponds to `CL_​OUT_​OF_​HOST_​MEMORY`

Which are the tracks which allow to fix this ?

### Partial solution

By compiling with Intel compilers (`icc` and `icpc`), compilation is performed well and code is running fine. I don't understand why it doesn't work with `GNU gcc/g++-8` compiler. If someone had an idea ...

Comment: To help you out with the error: I think I found the issue and I have updated my answer. Also: What value does `status` have after calling `clCreateKernel`?

Comment: I get the error `status = -44` after `clCreateKernel` from `cl.h` file and as illustrated in my **UPDATE2** which corresponds to `CL_INVALID_PROGRAM`. Have you got an idea about this error ? Missing a pragma in kernel code ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! clBuildProgram expects a reference to the device with "&", like this: status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &devices[current_device], NULL, NULL, NULL);    In case this does not solve it: The error -44 can be quite difficult and a result of threading issues as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63263231/9178992 . In that case, isolate the essential code and try if it works then.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX . I am using for compilation the `AMD APP SDK 3.0`which is pretty old now, maybe this is the cause of my issue. Is there an OpenCL SDK more recent on `Debian 10 Buster` ?

Comment: It seems that `AMD APP SDK 3.0` is only for AMD GPU, not NVIDIA GPU : I think in particular about `libOpenCL.so` dynamic library.

Comment: The OpenCL headers should work cross-vendor. Here is the headers from Nvidia CUDA toolkit 10.1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992

Comment: I really doubt it's an Installation issue. You only need the graphics driver and the header files. Hmm, maybe as last resort, write a minimum OpenCL example from scratch (some vector addition or whatever) and see at which point it fails.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX Sorry, I made a mistake in the version of cuda I use : I downloaded the OpenCL headers and libraries from the link of the post. But it still generates a -44 error at execution. Are there OpenCL headers and libOpenCL.so into cuda-drivers or cuda packages on Debian 10 Buster (I have installed cuda-drivers 11.4) ?

Comment: @ProjectPhysX . I must mention that I took over this code initially developped with OpenCL 1.x. Maybe this is the source of my troubles ? `cuda-drivers` has OpenCL 2.x, hasn't it ? However, whatever the version, it is compiling. What do you think about this specification ?

Comment: Nvidia does only support OpenCL 1.2.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX. If I can compile with `AMD APP SDK 3.0`, I think my code uses OpenCL 1.2. So the issue comes from other where.

Comment: Another thing came to my mind: do you create `context` with `clCreateContext` somewhere? If `context` is `nullptr`, `program` will never be valid in the first place. See EDIT 2 in my updated answer.

Comment: Note: the IP-address links in this post are obviously highly temporary, and thus this post can be said to be missing a [mcve]. Please replace these with inline copies of each file. If that is not possible then the question will need to be put on hold.

Comment: @halfer . Sorry but this is the only way I found to provide the full source instead of copy/paste at each time in my post all the source, that would be annoying for reader.

Comment: I can assure you it is off-topic as it stands, and will be voting to close based on that assessment as soon as the bounty expires. I would recommend that you change your approach.

Comment: @halfer . What would you suggest as solution to provide the full source ?

Comment: If the full source won't fit into the question, the question should not be posted, especially links to code are obviously temporary. In general the best solution to that problem is to cut the question down into a smaller problem that will fit. Do please read the "minimal example" link given earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kernel code looks good and the cache tiling implementation is correct. Only make sure that the number of bodies is a multiple of local size, or alternatively limit the inner for loop to the global size additionally.

OpenCL allows usage of multiple devices in parallel. You need to make a thread with a queue for each device *separately*. You also need to take care of device-device communications and synchronization manually. Data transfer happens over PCIe (you also can do remote direct memory access); but you can't use NVLink with OpenCL. This should not be an issue in your case though as you need only little data transfer compared to the amount of arithmetic.

A few more remarks:

- In many cases N-body requires FP64 to sum up the forces and resolve positions at very different length scales. However on the A6000, FP64 performance is very poor, just like on GeForce Ampere. FP32 would be significantly (~64x) faster, but is likely insufficient in terms of accuracy here. For efficient FP64 you would need an A100 or MI100.
- Instead of 1.0/sqrt, use rsqrt. This is hardware supported and almost as fast as a multiplication.
- Make sure to use either FP32 float (1.0f) or FP64 double (1.0) literals consistently. Using double literals with float triggers double arithmetic and casting of the result back to float which is much slower.

EDIT: To help you out with the error message: Most probably the error at `clCreateKernel` (what value does `status` have after calling `clCreateKernel`?) hints that `program` is invalid. This might be because you give [`clBuildProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html) a vector of 2 devices, but set the number of devices to only 1 and also have `context` only for 1 device. Try

```c
status = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &devices[current_device], NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

with only a single device.

To go multi-GPU, create two threads on the CPU that run `NBody::setupCL()` independently for GPUs 0 and 1, and then do synchronization manually.

EDIT 2:
I see nowhere that you create `context`. Without a valid context, `program` will be invalid, so `clBuildProgram` will throw error `-44`.
Call

```c
context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &devices[current_device], NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

before you do anything with `context`.

Comment: Thanks for your reactivity, I have added the following lines but still `-44 error` at the execution. Instead of putting all the concerned code, I provide you the following link to download the source file : http://31.207.36.11/NBody.cpp and the Makefile used for compilation : http://31.207.36.11/Makefile . Maybe you will find some errors but I would like mostly know why I get this `error -44` . Regards

Comment: I've gone through your code in detail and it looks fine to me. Only thing is, you could check `status` of `clCreateContext` and see if it is fine. Other than that, error `-44` can be caused by threading issues that are really hard to debug. Your best bet is to write an isolated, minimal OpenCL example like a vector addition and see how far you can get there.

Comment: I have taken over the debug of my code. You can see that troubles begin as soon as I try to create the Kernel code. I have provided the content of my Kernel code. If you could take a look at this **UPDATE4**. Best regards

Comment: Error `-44` is tough to debug, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63263231/9178992 I would advise to start with the simplest possible OpenCL Hello World program and see if you still get the error.